# SQL query returns empty result to ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Am trying to populate "Reigons" dropdownlist based on value of other dropdownlist which is "city" using php and javascript, the code does work put when it come to appending regions names and ID's to the select tag it Returns 
nothing despite they are exist in database!
Note: there is no problem with the SQL query because it works perfectly when i execute it on wampserver

Here is my DB (HWP):

```
CREATE TABLE `cities` (
`city_id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`city_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY  (`city_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `city_name` (`city_name`));

CREATE TABLE `reigons` (
`city_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
`reigon_id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`reigon_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`reigon_id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `reigons_name` (`reigon_name`));

 INSERT INTO `cities` (`city_id`, `city_name`) VALUES 
 (3, 'ALJAZERA'),
 (1, 'Khartoum'),
 (2, 'RED SEA');

 INSERT INTO `reigons` (`city_id`, `reigon_id`, `reigon_name`) VALUES 
(1, 1, 'Khartoum'),(1, 2, 'Bahri'),(1, 3, 'Um dorman'),
(2, 4, 'Read sea North'),(2, 5, 'Read sea South'),(3, 6, 'Baant'),
(3, 7, 'Soriba');
```

**Home.php:**

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); 
$db=mysql_select_db("hwp",$con);   
$query2 = mysql_query("select * from cities;") or die (mysql_error());?>
<select name="city" id="city" onchange="get_reg(this.value)">
    <option value="defult"> -Select City- </option>
    <?php
    while ($f2=mysql_fetch_array($query2)) {
    echo ('<option value="'.$f2['city_id'].'">'. $f2['city_name'].'</option>');}
    ?>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function get_reg(city)
   {
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: 'getreg.php',
     data: city,
     success: function(html) {
       $("#reigon").html(html);
    }});
  }
</script>

<select name="reigon" id="reigon">  
    <option value="defult"> -Select Reig- </option>                     
</select>
```

**getreg.php:**

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("hwp");
$city= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["city"]);
$query1 = mysql_query("select * from reigons where city_id= '$city'") or   die(mysql_error());
  while ($f1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) 
    {
        echo '<option value="', $f1['reigon_id'] ,'">', $f1['reigon_name'],'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Help please.

Comment: data: city, should be data: {city:city},

Comment: Problem Solved! Thank You Very Much @SameerJain :)